# UITextView adding new line unintentionally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a scroll view which contains a UITextField and a UITextView. The UITextField return key is "Next" and when this is pressed I call [myTextView becomeFirstResponder]; A random new line is inserted into my textview so I start on the second line. How do I avoid this?

Also important to note that this does not happen when I tap directly on the UITextView rather than tapping the next key.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will make things much better, if you share some code. And are you sure you are not setting some thing to textView.text property...?

Comment: This is all created in interface builder so I don't have anything to share. I have no code in my implementation files currently

Comment: You say you have no code but your question states that you call `[myTextView becomeFirstResponder];`. That's a contradiction. You obviously do have code.

Comment: Lol sorry my mistake I forgot about the textFieldShouldReturn method. But at least I know its an iOS bug. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

One solution to solve this is when you implement the `textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method, be sure to return `NO`, and not `YES`. By returning `NO`, the newline isn't passed on to the text field.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    // move to next field or whatever you need
    [myTextView becomeFirstResponder];

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Both work how about an upvote for everyone here today :)

Comment: Awesome! This one really works! Thanks! textFieldShouldReturn YES actually passes the newline. With NO, it doesn't.

Answer (score 12):

Okay, this behaviour is due to a bug in iOS when becoming firstresponder within same run loop by using next button. To over come this you should do this manually. 
First resign first responder from a textFied, and then make textView as a first responder. like this. Implement this delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textView performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to do this. See my answer.

Comment: Both work how about an upvote for everyone here today :)

Comment: Why resign the first responder on the `textField` first? Why not just call the delayed `becomeFirstResponder` on the `textView`?

Answer (score 0):

Similar idea to `performSelector`, but using asynchronous dispatch queue (Swift 4 version):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.myTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
   }
   return true
}
```