# Let cursor go to new line when tapping return button in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, enter

I have a subclass of `UITextView`, when I input some text and click on the `enter` button, the cursor will disappear. I want the result is add a new line and the cursor shows on the begin of the new line.

I found there are same questions on this website, but DOES NOT WORK FOR ME. I hope some one can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new line by tapping the return key in UITextView ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587912/how-to-create-a-new-line-by-tapping-the-return-key-in-uitextview-ios)

Comment: Yes, but the accepted solution does not work for me.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot/gif of what you are currently getting?