# UITextView becomeFirstResponder() adds new line

Tags: ios, swift

I'm quite new to iOS/Swift and I have a strange behaviour when setting a `UITextView` as a first responder (when touching `next` from the previous `UITextField`). It automatically inserts a new line in the `UITextView`. The code:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    nameTextField.delegate = self
    descriptionTextView.delegate = self
  }

  func textFieldShouldReturn(nameTextField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    descriptionTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
    return true
  }

  func textView(descriptionTextView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if (text == "\n") {
      descriptionTextView.resignFirstResponder()
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

A new line is always added and i press `next`, even if there's already text or a new line.
On the first `next` here is what happens (the cursor is automatically on the **2nd** line).
[image]

If I go back to the text field and press next again, the cursor is on the **3rd** line).
[image]

Comment: Haven't checked, but it would seem normal to me that the text of an UITextView always end with a newline (so that all lines end with one), so upon first use, if the existing text is empty, it would add it.

Comment: I completed my question, it happens even if there text in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView adding new line unintentionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077842/uitextview-adding-new-line-unintentionally)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Return false in `textFieldShouldReturn`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(nameTextField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    descriptionTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
    return false
}
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077842/uitextview-adding-new-line-unintentionally)

Comment: Wow! Save my time Thanks!