# Hiding a UIButton when a text field is clicked on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

New to Swift and making a simple to-do app.

I am trying to get it so that when a UI TextField is clicked on, a certain button should be hidden. It's only when the user presses enter after typing in a task that the button should appear.

I have an IBAction set up for my text field to hide the UIButton when it is clicked on like so, but it doesn't work:

```
  @IBAction func textFieldClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        self.cellButton.isHidden = true

}
```

And I have set up my textfieldshouldreturn function when the user presses enter like so:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.cellButton.isHidden = false
    self.cellButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Does an IBAction for text field only respond when enter is pressed? I tried messing with flags but that didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an `IBAction` for this. Instead, implement another `UITextFieldDelegate` method - `textFieldDidBeginEditing`.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.cellButton.isHidden = true
}
```

This delegate is called when a text field becomes the first responder.

On a slightly unrelated note, it's best to return `false` instead of `true` from your `textFieldShouldReturn` method.

Comment: Wow, easy fix thanks a lot! I always forget about all the delegate methods. May I ask why you say it's best to return false instead of true for the textFieldShouldReturn method?

Comment: It's only an issue in one obscure case. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077842/uitextview-adding-new-line-unintentionally) and my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use delegates method `textFieldDidDeginEditing` and hide button.